# Loading custom fonts without using a context

Tags: java, android

I already know Java and how it works, but I am new with the android related stuff. I have a font I want to use, and I want to load it in a separate class, however all the sites I found that show an example require the context from the `MainActivity` object, because it uses the `getAssets()` function. I need to load the font in without using that function.

Example of what I was shown

```
// This works, but I don't have access to the getContext().getAssets()
// in my separate class. Is there anyway I can do this without this function or XML?
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/ExampleFont.ttf");
```

Comment: Pass your context to your “helper class” (separate class) from your activity.

Comment: I would prefer if I didn't pass it to the class because I would like for it to be completely separate from standard code to help keep my code neat and orderly.

Answer (score 0):

create CustomTextView class and use it your xml directly as Regular textview like below

> customtextview class file

```
    public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/opensans.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

use this as

```
 <core.com.example.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Test text with custom font"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                />
```

**UPDATE**

As @EugenPechanec commented you can try this method which demonstrate [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Comment: Typefaces are heavy objects and take long to load. You should definitely employ some sort of cache instead of loading the same typeface obejct in each instance of your custom text view. /// With the introduction of font support  in the framework and support library there's no reason to even attempt this. See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: @EugenPechanec thank you for sharing such info, Actually I'm not aware of this method of setting font to TextView. BTW you can elaborate your answer which may help others... :)

Comment: There's no need to """elaborate""" when there are perfectly fine guides available. What's wrong with reading the official documentation? It's written in easy to understand English.